# SQL date function - first date of month til current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following function which extracts statistics from a website for last month from the current date. What I need to change in code below to make it work to get stats for example from 01-11-2015 till now for a monthly and same for rest of the intervals ( 3m, 6m and 1 year ).

```
protected function duration($params) {
    if($params->get('stats_duration')=='last_month') {
        return 'AND datum_ura >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)'; 
    } elseif($params->get('stats_duration')=='three_months') {
        return 'AND datum_ura >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH)';
    } elseif($params->get('stats_duration')=='six_months') {
        return 'AND datum_ura >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 6 MONTH)';
    } elseif($params->get('stats_duration')=='twelve_months') {
        return 'AND datum_ura >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 YEAR)';
    } elseif($params->get('stats_duration')=='all') {
        return '';
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming using MySQL.

For current month, you can just use the condition as follow:

```
AND datum_ura >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

For last 3 months, just extend it into this:

```
AND datum_ura >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
```